# Alter column text to varchar SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

How can I alter a column of type `text` in a SQL Server 2000 table, and change it to `varchar`?

I tried with

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ALTER COLUMN myColumn varchar(8000) NULL
GO
```

and the error is

> No se puede modificar la columna 'MyColumn' porque es 'text'

Comment: You may have to add a new column, perform an update (perhaps in batches), drop the old column, and rename the new column. Note that this isn't a limitation in modern versions of SQL Server... why is the question tagged with 2008 R2? You shouldn't get an error there.

Comment: Thansks Aaron, utilice your solution